# Doctrine assignment error: Cannot assign Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection to property

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

i have a upload from where i would like to show all the catégories from the database but i keep getting an error with the EntityType i don't know why was working before.

This is the error: `Cannot assign Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection to property App\Entity\Category::$posts  of type Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection`

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\CategoryRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CategoryRepository::class)
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private int $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private string $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Post::class, mappedBy="Category_id")
     */
    private ArrayCollection $Posts;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->posts = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Post[]
     */
    public function gePosts(): Collection
    {
        return $this->posts;
    }

    public function addPost(Post $post): self
    {
        if (!$this->posts->contains($post)) {
            $this->$posts[] = $posts;
            $post->setCategoryId($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removePost(Post $post): self
    {
        if ($this->posts->removeElement($post)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($post->getCategoryId() === $this) {
                $post->setCategoryId(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->getName();
    }
}
```

The upload Form where i am getting the error

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Form\Post;

use App\Entity\Category;
use App\Entity\Post;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\File;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;

class UploadType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param \Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                                        $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', TextType::class, [
                
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank([
                        'message' => 'Please enter a valid Title. '
                    ])
                ]
            ])
            ->add('category', EntityType::class, [
                'mapped' => false,
                'class' => Category::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'expanded' => true
            ])
            ->add('poster', FileType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'constraints' => [
                    new File([
                        'maxSize' => '6000K',
                        'mimeTypes' => [
                            'image/x-png',
                            'image/jpeg',
                        ],
                        'mimeTypesMessage' => 'Please upload a image file.'
                    ])
                ]
            ])
            ->add('description', TextareaType::class, [
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank([
                        'message' => 'Please enter a valid Title. '
                    ])
                ]
            ])
            ->add('mediainfo', TextareaType::class, [
                'required' => false,
            ]);
    }
    
    /**
     * @param \Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Post::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

in the Post entity

```php
   /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Category::class, inversedBy="posts")
     */
    private Category $Category_id;
```

Environment info:

- Symfony 5.2.5 (env: dev, debug: true)
- PHP Version: 8.0.3
- Database Driver & Version: 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1

Answer (score 39):

After some digging a found the answer changing the ArrayCollection to Collection fixed my issue

change:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Post::class, mappedBy="Category_id")
 */
private \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $posts;
```

to:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Post::class, mappedBy="Category_id")
 */
private \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $posts;
```

Comment: This is Nov. 4 2021 and you just save my life from sleepless night. Thanks so much @kunwara. This made my day !

Answer (score 9):

The problem is in th type hinting (ArrayCollection => Collection)

change:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Post::class, mappedBy="Category_id")
 */
private ArrayCollection $Posts;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->posts = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

by:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Post::class, mappedBy="Category_id")
 */
private Collection $Posts;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->posts = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`$this->$posts[] = $posts;`

Looks like this line should be:

`$this->$posts[] = $post;`

Answer (score 1):

```
private ArrayCollection $posts;
```

is a direct dependence to Doctrine :

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
```

If you desagree, perhaps because it breaks the SOLID "D", try to use the pure php pseudo type Iterable (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.iterable.php), like this:

```
private iterable $posts;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case this can help others, I had the same exact problem in my entity class. It turned out that for some reasons the `Use` statement for `Collection` class was missing in my file. Make sure you have these two lines:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
```